# What's difference between perror and fprintf to stderr?

Tags: c, linux

I know both can work as error messages,

```
perror(" ");
fprintf(stderr, " ");
```

but what are really differences between them? What are advantages/disadvantages of each ?

Comment: it's just that you cannot pass formatting arguments to `perror`. so it's slightly faster...

Comment: `perror("foo")` is basically equivalent to `fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s\n", strerror(errno))`. I like to use `fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s.\n", strerror(errno))`, but only because the lack of a `.` at the end of the `perror()` output bugs me. Remember that if you encounter a *fatal* error, for example a `malloc()` fails, or the program cannot open a required file, you'll want to *both* report the error, and abort the program using either `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or `abort();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the `perror()` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> The perror() function shall map the error number accessed through the
>   symbol errno to a language-dependent error message, which shall be
>   written to the standard error stream as follows:
>
> - First (if s is not a null pointer and the character pointed to by s is not the null byte), the string pointed to by s followed by a
>     <colon> and a <space>.
> - Then an error message string followed by a <newline>.
>
> The contents of the error message strings shall be the same as those
>   returned by strerror() with argument errno.

So,

```
perror( " " );
```

will emit something like

```
 : invalid argument
```

to `stderr`, depending on the current value of `errno`.

But

```
fprintf( stderr, " " );
```

will emit only a space character to `stderr` and not print the string representation of the current `errno` value.

`fprintf( stderr, " " );` in isolation is pretty useless.  `perror( " " );` will provide data about the current value of `errno`.

Comment: So it will be always good practice using perror to verify functions returning values, perror automatically sends to stderr without passing any arguments

Comment: @jorgesaraiva In general, yes, since that would give you some indication of *why* something failed.